# Krita: How to include references in exported image file?

Tags: export, krita

I'm trying out the new reference tool in Krita, but that turned out to be a big mistake. I need to export my file as a JPEG/PNG image, but I also want to include all of my reference images, since it's for an assignment, and my teacher wants to see my moodboard. When I export to an image, it saves only the paint layers I have created, excluding the reference images, considering they are already embedded in the .kra file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to export the reference images. You would have to add them in a layer and arrange them to export it. If you don't have the reference images separately you can make a copy of the kra file rename it's extension to .zip and see if it contains the reference images. KRA is just a zip file with different extension.